# How to reset containers in Microsoft OneNote

Tags: microsoft-onenote

When I create a new page in OneNote using the Windows desktop client, the container works in such a way to be 'responsive' when viewing in a mobile device (Android in this case). I.e. the text reflows to fit the width of the screen.

However, if I re-size the container (using the desktop client), the text often no longer fits the screen on the mobile version. This seems reasonable since I may have wanted to re-size the container for good reasons.

**How can I reset the container size back to a default setting so that I can recover the text re-flow in the mobile version?**

*(An alternative solution would be to force-reflow in the mobile device but I don't see an option for this. Without a solution, I would be forced to re-create the content in a new page. However, I would then lose the archiving, history, etc.)*

Comment: The reflow also works in the desktop version when resizing the window. I haven't been able to reset a previously resized container to this behaviour though.

Comment: Under VIEW tab there is a zoom size. I am not sure but perhaps that could help your case. For example if I resize the window by using touch on laptop screen and I want to go back to previous window size then VIEW will do it.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me in OneNote 2016. Here, I am trying to restore dynamic width of the "main" text box of a page.

1. Grab the container's top edge with the mouse and drag away from its default location
2. Click in the page title to get the cursor there
3. Hit TAB to create a new default container under the title
4. Press ENTER and/or add some other content to the new container to keep it around (A totally empty container will go away. You may want to add a line or something as a visual cue)
5. With the mouse, click the top edge of the original container and start dragging
6. While dragging, press the SHIFT key
7. Drag the original container on top of the new one. Holding the SHIFT key should cause the content to be "merged" into the new container.

All of the original content should now be in a new container that is dynamically sized relative to the application window.

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished by installing [Onetastic for OneNote](http://getonetastic.com/) and using this very simple macro I just created:
[Reset Container Size](https://getonetastic.com/macroland&id=B5BC4260C5994EE2841CBA6AEDCC474C)

Using it should reset your container size back to automatic.

Comment: This looks very interesting .. I'll give it a go. Thanks :)

Comment: Should be noted that Onetastic is a pay-for service with a limited number of uses allowed per macro.  So it is a solution, but only temporary until you pay the dev.

This type of "free" account means "demo" account in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is, for example, write a single letter elsewehre in the page to create a "new resizeable" container and then move all your text from the "fixed width" container into the "new resizeable" container.

Important: make sure that you move the text by selecting one of the "paragraph" icon in the original container, otherwise it won't work.